# spring cloud contract - use the request's body as the response body

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

in spring cloud contract (v1.2.5) using this contract:

```
    Contract.make {
        description "update sthg"
        request {
            method PUT()
            url value($(consumer('/path/to/sthg'),
                    producer(execute('somePutPathPath(0,\"xxx\")'))))
            body(producer(
                    file('files/givens/my-body.json')
            ))
        }
        response {
            status 200
            headers {
                contentType(applicationJson())
            }
            body(fromRequest().body())
        }
    }
```

I get an error when generating the tests

```
 org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:generateTests failed:net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected character ({) at position 1. -> [Help 1]
```

but everything is fine if i use: **body(someProp: fromRequest().body())**

```
    Contract.make {
        description "update sthg"
        request {
            method PUT()
            url value($(consumer('/path/to/sthg'),
                    producer(execute('somePutPathPath(0,\"xxx\")'))))
            body(producer(
                    file('files/givens/my-body.json')
            ))
        }
        response {
            status 200
            headers {
                contentType(applicationJson())
            }
            body(someProp: fromRequest().body())
        }
    }
```

**How could I set the body response to be the request's body.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using **request.getBody()** instead of : *body(fromRequest().body())*

```
  body($(
            c(request.getBody()),
            p(file('some.json'))
    ))
```